# smearing in Linux, but not in Windows

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I must have a Linux library out of wack since the following image has "smears" on the colors.  Is there a better term?  On my Windows 7 RStudio it works fine.  this image is from a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the following are the libraries:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
```

the code that generates this image is:

```
ggplot(data = world2) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), color 
    = "white") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]